# Kendo aggregate client footer template plus sign throws an exception

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to calculate a grand total in my aggregate footer but this code isn't working for me.

Please help.

> .ClientFooterTemplate("Grand total: #=kendo.toString(sum+sum, 'C')#");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix a few English issues.  Perhaps you should share what data you do get with your code.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel my reply solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected as the plus sign is removed from the template using regex. In current case better approach would be calling external function where the calculation will be done.

```
.ClientFooterTemplate("Grand total: #=calculateAggregate(sum)#")
```

JavaScipt:

```
functio calculateAggregate(sum) {
  return kendo.toString(sum + sum, 'C');
}
```